# separa string para ponerlo en un datagrid

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hola me podrían ayudar a separar ese string que optengo de una lista separarlo y poner donde  dice name y password en columnas de de un datagrid ya he intentado con slipt pero no lo he logrado

```
foreach (string item in mk.Read())
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(item);
               x+=item;

            }
            string[] words = Regex.Split(x, "=");

            foreach (var item in words)
            {                   
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);

                //if (item == "name")
                //    listBox2.Items.Add(item.Count());


            }
```

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez puedas hacer algo así:

```
string[] words = x.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string n = null;
string p = null;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
{                   
    switch (words[i]){
        case "name":
            n = words[i + 1];
            break;
        case "password":
            p = words[i + 1];
            break;
    }
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(n) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)) {
    listBox2.Items.Add(p);
    listBox1.Items.Add(n);
}
```

En el ejemplo cuando encuentro un nombre lo agrego al listBox1 y cuando encuentro una clave lo agrego al listBox2, pero podés modificarlo para que lo agregue a donde lo necesites.

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!

Comment: sip casi me funciona solo que en un lisbox me inprime los 3 name y en el otro me inprime solo 2 contraseñas pero eso se debe a que la primera linea solo tiene name y no tiene contraseña

Comment: Acabo de modificar el ejemplo, ahora debería funcionar como necesitás.

Comment: casi pero ahora solo me inprime el ultimmo

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(n) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
                    {
                        if(!listBox2.Items.Contains(p))
                        listBox2.Items.Add(p);

                        if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(n))
                        listBox1.Items.Add(n);
                    } agrege esas 2 lineas y lo meti dendro del for y si me funciono

Comment: no se que le parese esa modificacion

Comment: Si metés el if dentro del for va a hacer la consulta por cada posición del vector, además si el string tiene más parámetros después del password va a agregar varias veces los nombres y passwords a las listas.

Comment: sip eso lo controle con solo verifico si esta en el lisbox y si no esta lo mete

Comment: hola ahirita estoy intentaddo que me muestre al info que esta en uptime pero no melo muestra

Comment: Crea un nueva pregunta con el código que tienes hasta ahora, para poder ver el problema

Comment: Ok ya la creo grqcias por la ayuda